# Path problem after migration to new server

Tags: migration, mediawiki

I migrated my mediawiki to a server with a different hostname (completely different machine).

after export/import the database and changing the hostname in the web-config file i was able to log in to mediawiki-1.34.0

But after clicking on a page (wiki-entry), the old hostname will be used. It seems that the old hostname is saved somewhere in the database as well.

I used this Howto: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Moving_a_wiki

Best Regards,
M

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to update [$wgServer](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgServer) and related variables.

You might need to invalidate some caches as well, to force articles to be re-rendered. That depends greatly on wiki settings and your overall infrastructure; see e.g. [$wgCacheEpoch](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgCacheEpoch).